# Showing a dynamic size list in XAML (readonly)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to show a list of "properties" in my application. A property is simply a name/value pair. The number of properties is dynamic.

The best way to do this? The only thing I can come up with is creating a ListView with an ItemTemplate. But then the items are selectable, and that's not what I want. If I make the list read-only, it becomes gray. Don't like that either.

Anyone has a better suggestion?

Comment: I hope your question is not *readonly* ;) (just a joke)

Comment: Naw, if it were it would have been in square brackets [readonly].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Use a `Grid` for `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` with `SharedSizeGroup` if you want all items to line up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: 
http://www.codeplex.com/wpg or here 
http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!448.entry

They are both implmentations of PropertyGrid from WinForms